# Can a photoshop action or script load/save swatch, and choose color from it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions, swatches

I was wondering if it is possible for a photoshop action to choose foreground or background color from the swatch. 
I have tried doing it, but instead of picking from swatch it is always taking a fixed value.
I am trying the script to pick color from the swatch sequentially. For example, if there are 5 colors in the swatch, it should pick 1st, 2nd ...upto 5th color.

Comment: How easily / often do you need to update the colors you want to cycle through? Given that it looks like getting a swatch color is tough, if not impossible, [I made this script as a sort of a test.](https://gist.github.com/joonaspaakko/347c270f15bc1d11efe9). Also if you didn't know already, you can set a shortcut key to launch a script.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in script. Tom Krcha has a script which you may be able to adapt (Add A Color To Swatches Panel In Photoshop Using ExtendScript/JSX):

```
var red = 255;
var green = 0;
var blue = 0;
var name = "Red";

var addColorDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();
// Get reference to Swatches panel
var swatchesPanelReference = new ActionReference();
swatchesPanelReference.putClass(stringIDToTypeID('colors'));
addColorDescriptor.putReference(stringIDToTypeID('null'), swatchesPanelReference);
// Setup a swatch and give it a name
var descriptorSwatch = new ActionDescriptor();
descriptorSwatch.putString( stringIDToTypeID('name'), name);
// Add RGB color information to the swatch
var descriptorColor = new ActionDescriptor();
descriptorColor.putDouble(stringIDToTypeID('red'), red);
descriptorColor.putDouble(stringIDToTypeID('grain'), green); // grain = green
descriptorColor.putDouble(stringIDToTypeID('blue'), blue);
// Add RGB to the swatch
descriptorSwatch.putObject( stringIDToTypeID('color'), stringIDToTypeID('RGBColor'), descriptorColor);
// Add swatch to the color descriptor
addColorDescriptor.putObject( stringIDToTypeID('using'), stringIDToTypeID('colors'), descriptorSwatch);
// Send to Photoshop
executeAction( stringIDToTypeID('make'), addColorDescriptor, DialogModes.NO);
```

ref: http://tomkrcha.com/?p=3890

Comment: Thank you very much ! How can I pick color from swatch using script ?

Comment: @S.M. The script: "Add a color to swatches panel in Photoshop". I'm pretty sure KJP meant this script as a starting point. It's not a straight up solution, as it does the opposite of what you want. Although, I have to ask. Let's say you have 10 swatches. how did you plan to choose what swatch to use?

Comment: @ Joonas. Thanks for your reply. What I am really trying to achieve is, pick colors as foreground sequentially. Lets say I have 10 colors in swatches. I am trying to pick 1st, 2nd, 3rd... upto 10th. Is there a way ?

Comment: @S.M. You mean like: press a hotkey once: Swatch #1 gets selected as the foreground color, press a hotkey for the second time: Swatch #2  gets selected as the foreground color... etc?

Comment: @ Joonas Yes . Like a loop. It will choose swatch#1 do an operation, and choose swatch#2.. and continue until it have picked all colors in the swatches.

Comment: @S.M. Based on some googling, it seems that picking a color from the swatches panel is not as easy as it is with Indesign or Illustrator. I was fairly confident that you could do that, but looking at the code that Script Listener puts out when you pick a color from swatches, I don't think it's possible. Script listener doesn't do like `pick a color from swatch 3` or something. It actually just picks static rgb values, much like it would by using color picker on anything. I could be wrong. At least I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Based on some more googling, I'd suggest looking at the scripts available in xbytor's xtools library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ps-scripts/files/xtools/v2.2betas/ particularly the ColorSwatches script. Might help. Good luck.

Comment: My feelings about this right now are that it would be easier to make a replacement extension for swatches for this purpose :)=

Comment: @Joonas - I agree :)